# Got page not found when use extra arguments in express router

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So i have a 404 handler and a router file:

404 handler:

```
app.all("*", (req, res, next) => {
    res.status(404).json({
      "status": "failed",
      "message": "woops, page not found..."
    })
})
```

Router:

```
orderRouter.route('/')
        .post((req, res, next, optionalData) => {
            res.status(200).json({
                "status": "ok"
            })
        })

module.exports = orderRouter
```

As we can see, i add extra arguments in middleware, that is "***optionalData***".

When i access the route **/** method **POST**, i got 404 result.

But when i define that optionalData = undefined, it works. I got results "status": "ok".

```
(req, res, next, optionalData = undefined)
```

But why? what happen here..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Express regular request handlers are expected to have no more than 3 arguments as you can verify [here](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/28db2c2c5cf992c897d1fbbc6b119ee02fe32ab1/lib/router/layer.js#L89).

And looking up `Function.length`:

> length is a property of a function object, and indicates how many
> arguments the function expects, i.e. the number of formal parameters.
> This number excludes the rest parameter and **only includes parameters
> before the first one with a default value**.

It becomes clear why the second function works and the first one doesn't:

```
(function(a, b, c, d = undefined) {}).length === 3
(function(a, b, c, d) {}).length === 4
```